# Not able to run my testng.xml file from maven using eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run testng.xml file form maven but it fails. However, if I run the test file directly, my test case runs fine.

I provide the code snippet for testng.xml as well as my pom.xml.

testng.xml

```
<suite name="Tina5s" verbose="1" >
  <test name="New Object" >
    <classes>
      <class name="Login.NewObj" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

pom.xml

```
<build>  
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>
      <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>TestData/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration> 
    </plugin>
  </plugins>  
</build>
```

Comment: Please provide some more information about what happens when you run it from maven. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Why would you like to use testng.xml file? If you correctly name your test like `WhatEverTest.java` it will automatically picked up by maven-surefire-plugin..